# retrieving fontSize from html element

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

I am trying to animate something.

I set the the **default font-size** in the **html** element in css.

I am trying to get the font-size that I set in the css, and then use it in javascript.

I tried this...

```
var somevariable = getElementById('HtmlId');
var anothervariable = somevariable.style.fontSize;
```

but I get NAN.

I have tried parsing the variable assuming that it returns a string.

I want to get the css

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use jQuery :

```
var fontSize = parseInt(jQuery('#HtmlId').css('font-size'), 10);
```

use of pure JavaScript may not return desired result, as if you run following lines separately in console (site:stackoverflow.com). results are different.

```
document.body.style.fontSize // ''
jQuery('body').css('font-size') // 13px
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be :-

`var somevariable = document.getElementById('HtmlId');`

The line after that is fine.

Comment: No, even fixed that way, the code gets just the `font-size` value set in a `style` attribute of the `body` element. If font size is defaulted or it if is set in a normal way, like CSS rule `body { font-size: 12pt`, the `fontSize` property has an empty value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-jquery solution...works even if font is not not set in CSS. Kind've clumsy...

```
var myElem = document.getElementById("myElementId");
var fontSize = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(myElem, null).fontSize;
```

edit- someone else saw what the real error probably is... missed "document."

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jquery, you could do it this way:

`var somevariable = $("#HtmlId").css("font-size");`